# VBA MS Access Getting the start date in a database

Tags: sql, vba, dao, recordset

I have a MS Access database and inside it I import tables from an external source every month.  What I want to do is get the earliest date in the database since it is out of order.  I am creating forms and so far this is what I have:

```
'Get start and end date
Dim DBGeo As DAO.Database
Dim rstStartDate As DAO.Recordset

Set DBGeo = CurrentDb

varStartDate = "SELECT [time] FROM [" & cboTableName & "] ORDER BY [time] ASC LIMIT 1;"
MsgBox (varStartDate)
Set rstStartDate = DBGeo.OpenRecordset(varStartDate, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

The field name is called time and I know that is a keyword but I dont want to change it or else I have to change it in all the tables.  CboTableName has the name of the table I am using.

Im not great at this stuff so I am sure it is something simple.  Thank you

Comment: What problem are you encountering?  For what it's worth, this is probably a better approach, `SELECT min ([time]) FROM [" & cboTableName & "]` but I don't know that your SQL should cause a problem.

Comment: You've not explained a problem with the code you've posted or asked any sort of question. What specifically can we help you with?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I get run time error 3138  Syntax error in ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT TOP 1 Table1.Time
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Table1.Time;